# Form handling and data posting - how

Tags: javascript, forms, oop, local-storage

I am all relatively new to this form handling and such.

say I have a page two buttons that each time I click on one of them a form should be opened to enter

a. new recipe -
b. new ingredient.

there should be already - few ingredient items on the database (which I am not quite sure how to get them there on the first place) and 1 recipe (that is supposed to be made out of those ingredients)

there should also be new recipe form - and in the bottom of the form there should be (all the) ingredients list

something like this: [https://es6-mobile2020-2021.netlify.app/](https://es6-mobile2020-2021.netlify.app)

I already made a class for the dishRecipe and class for ingredient,

`

```
class Ingredient {
    constructor(id, name, img, calories) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.image = image;
        this.calories = calories;
    }   
    get calories(){return this.calories;}
    
    Render() {
        let ingredientdStr = `
            <figure id="ingrdnt_${this.id}">
                <figtitle>Ingredient details:</figtitle>
                <ul>
                    <li>id: ${this.id}</li>
                    <li><img src="${this.image}" alt="ingredient img" title= "${this.name} is an ingredient" width="250px"></li>
                    <li>name: ${this.name}</li>
                    <li> calories:${this.calories}</li>
                </ul>  
            </figure>`
        return ingredientdStr;
    }
}
```

made template literal for both of the forms, yet I don't know how to make it work -

```
const recipeForm = `    
    <fieldset>
        <legend></legend> ${/* may be removed */''}
        <p>
            <label for="recipeName">Recipe name: </label>
            <input type="text" name="" id="recipeName">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="recipeMethod">Recipe Method: </label>
            <input type="text" name="" id="recipeMethod">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="recipeTime">Recipe Cooking time: </label>
            <input type="time" name="" id="recipeTime">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="recipeImage">Recipe image (url):</label>
            <input type="url" name="" id="recipeImage">
        </p>
    </fieldset>

        
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Choose ingredients: </legend>
            <label for="item${inum}">
                Add
                <input type="checkbox" name="" id="item${inum}">
                 ${ /*here there'd be the ingredient list */''}
                 ${ingredientList}
            </label>
        </fieldset>
`
```

like how to combine the input fields to work from the html with the local storage and from the local storage.
is it possible to "export" what's on the local storage to actual file? like - to add to a file multiple fields?

another thing: where it's noted  `${ingredientList}` there should be a chain of "rendered" ingredients.
what's the proper "begginer's" way to pull that kind of things? can use jquery
thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You're asking so many questions it's hard to know what you are stuck on exactly!

Comment: thanks for the feedback, I will try to narrow it down next time. it's my first question